# Defining command in base View model

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We would like define some button be visible in every page for a set of users. We defined button as control template for view and called out it in the pages that require them to be displayed.

```
<Button ImageSource="home_footer.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
        Command="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.HomeCommand}"/>
```

Here command is selected according to the binding context, i.e corresponding view model. Command need to written multiple times. I thought of including the command in base view model so that it needs to written only once. Is there any option for implementing this option.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: **We defined button as control template for view and called out it in the pages that require them to be displayed.** As FreakyAli said that I suggest you can use custom contentview to display some control, about more detailed info, you can take a look this article:https://taubensee.net/activitybutton-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 2):

In your BaseViewModel add a command

```
    public ICommand HomeCommand { get; set; }
```

In your base `ContentPage` add a bindable property that supplies you this command:

```
   public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Command),
        typeof(ICommand),
        typeof(ClassName),
        null
        );

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(CommandParameter),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(ClassName),
        null
        );
```

Supply a command to this property from the ContentPage

```
<base:CustomContentPage ....
Command="{Binding HomeCommand}">
```

Set it to your Button something like:

You can give it a better name to explain the behaviour,

Goodluck!

Feel free to get back if you have queries!

Comment: Where is home Command to defined? I have added  bindable property in ContentPage.

Comment: As I said HomeCommand is supposed to be in your BaseViewModel

Comment: I have defined Command in BaseView model and changed the Command binding in xaml as Command="{Binding HomeCommand}" but i am not able to run the command on button click. Is there any thing that I am missing

Comment: in BaseVM

`public ICommand HomeCommand { get; set; }`

in baseVM constructor

`HomeCommand = new Command(async () => await HomeNavigationClicked());`

Defined HomeNAvigationClicked()

`private async Task HomeNavigationClicked()
        {
            await NavigationService.RemoveBackStackAsync();
            await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync<PatientHomeViewModel>();
        }`

Am I following correct way

Comment: You seem to be doing the right thing, what I would suggest is you add your latest code in the question for us to check once!